# Does the delta-transfer algorithm used in rsync transfer part of a source file, i.e. subfile?

Tags: rsync

rsync is said to use delta-transfer algorithm to transfer files.

For a preexisting destination file with the same filename as a
    source file,

1. Is the delta-transfer algorithm used

   - only after rsync have decided to transfer the source file to the destination, or
   - during determining whether or not rsync will transfer the source file to the destination?
2. When rsync has decided to transfer the source file to the destination file,

   Does the delta-transfer algorithm transfer the difference between the source and destination files?

   Does the delta-transfer algorithm work at the "sub-file" level, by first calculating the patch file between the two files, and then transferring the patch
   file to the destination, and then applying  the patch file to the
   preexisting destination file to get an identical copy of the source
   file?

   If so, do rsync need to transfer the source file to the destination in order to calculate the patch file between the
   source and destination files? If yes, doesn't that contradict the purpose of the delta-transfer algorithm to avoid transferring the whole source file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

> only after rsync have decided to transfer the source file to the destination

Yes.

> during determining whether or not rsync will transfer the source file to the destination

No. Once `rsync` starts the delta algorithm, it is fully committed to updating the file.

> Does the delta-transfer algorithm transfer the difference between the source and destination files?

By default, yes. You can disable it with the `--whole-file` option. Note that what is sent by the delta-transfer algorithm is **not** literally a `diff` of the two files.

> Does the delta-transfer algorithm work at the "sub-file" level, by first calculating the patch file between the two files, and then transferring the patch file to the destination, and then applying the patch file to the preexisting destination file to get an identical copy of the source file?

No, because `rsync` does not assume that the sender has a copy of the destination's version of the file.

`rsync` uses rolling checksums to determine matching portions of the file without transferring the whole file in either direction. Of course, if there are no matches, the whole file will need to be sent.

Comment: Thanks. Is what is sent by the delta-transfer algorithm is part of the source file, i.e. subfile?

Comment: @Tim: https://rsync.samba.org/how-rsync-works.html

Comment: BTW, if doing a local sync (destination and source are on the same machine), rsync only transfers the entire file, rather than transferring deltas. You can override this with `--no-W`. (Note: all characters are lowercase, except the capital "W".)