# Why does --backup imply the delta-transfer algorithm, which in turn implies -u?

Tags: rsync

From http://www.jveweb.net/en/archives/2011/02/using-rsync-and-cron-to-automate-incremental-backups.html#jveweb_en_027_06

> Using the **--backup** parameter enables t**he delta-transfer algorithm**, so
>   the use of the **-u** parameter is not necessary.

1. How can we understand `--backup` implies the delta-transfer algorithm?
2. `-u, --update` skips files that are newer on the receiver. [The delta-transfer algorithm is to actually transfer a file, but not to make a decision whether this file will actually be transferred or not.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340708/does-the-delta-transfer-algorithm-used-in-rsync-transfer-part-of-a-source-file) So how does enabling delta-transfer algorithm imply `-u`?

Note that I found neither of the two are mentioned in the manpage of rsync, but I might miss something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Using the --backup parameter enables the delta-transfer algorithm, so the use of the -u parameter is not necessary.

Wrong! https://xkcd.com/386/ (someone is wrong on the Internet).

> How can we understand --backup implies the delta-transfer algorithm?

It doesn't. The delta-transfer algorithm is the default.

> So how does enabling delta-transfer algorithm imply -u?

It doesn't.

Comment: Thanks. (1). Since the link contains inaccuracy, is the link correct that the files that are backed up by `--backup` are exactly the destination files to be overwritten or to be deleted? Does `--backup` record the source files that don't exist on the destination and are to be transferred?  (2). When `--backup` backs up some destination file, does it backup the entire of the destination file or the "difference" between the preexisting destination file and the source file? In other words, does `--backup` copy files in a similar way to the delta-transfer algorithm?